# Google spreadsheets: prepend character for each cell with a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet doc with two columns:Column A and Column B.

I need formula in Column B to get the value in Column A with the sign '+' prepended for **each word**.

Take a look at the capture:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,SUBSTITUTE("+"&A:A," "," +")))`

Comment: Thanks. One more question: is there a way to just add the + sign only if the word has more than 3 characters? 

You answered the question and will accept it anyway.

Comment: @JPashs Try `=TRIM(JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(SPLIT(A1," "))>3," +"," ")&SPLIT(A1," "))))`

Comment: @JPashs also this arrayformula should work: `=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"(\w{4,})"," +$1")))`

Comment: awesome Max!   I got an arrayformula to work for 3 characters but it was far more complicated:  `=ArrayFormula(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(IF(LEN(SPLIT(A:A," "))>3," +"&SPLIT(A:A&"|"," ")," "&SPLIT(A:A&"|"," ")))),"|"))))`

Answer (score 1):

This formula also works:

`=JOIN(" +",SPLIT(A1," "))`

Regexreplace also good thing to make it with condition:
`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"(\w{4,})"," +$1")))`

to add + only for words which has more than 3 characters